# $refs no longer registering after vue/bootstrap-vue update

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, popover, bootstrap-vue

I updated bootstrap-vue in my laravel project and noticed that functionality that was previously working is now broken. The code has remained the same so it's the only thing I can think of.

I'm currently on vue@2.5.16 and bootstrap-vue@2.17.3

The issue is with one of the $refs not being registered.

The project is old and I am not the original author. I am also relatively inexperienced with vue, so I don't know what has changed in vue and bootstrap-vue since this code was originally written.

The issue is with a  component which wraps an input.

```
<b-container class="bv-example-row persons-second-part">
    <b-row class="">
        <b-col class="person" sm="2" v-for="(person, index) in persons" @click.prevent="doubleClick(person, index)" :key="index">
            <div v-show="person.deleted === false">
                <div v-show="(currentState === 2 || currentState === 3)" v-dragged="onDragged" :id="getId(index)" style="z-index: 999" class="jag-i-centrum-label-upper-left drag-me" v-text="person.name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <b-popover :target="getId(index)" triggers="focus" placement="top">
                <input v-model="person.comment" ref="popoverInput" placeholder="Skriv beskrivning">
            </b-popover>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
</b-container>
```

Here are the relevant functions

```
methods: {
    doubleClick(person, index) {
      this.clicks++;
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.clicks == 2) this.openPopup(person, index);
        this.clicks = 0;
      }, 200);
    },

    openPopup(person, index) {
      person.showContainer = !person.showContainer;
      let that = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        that.$root.$emit("bv::show::popover", "popover-" + index);
        const ref = that.getId(index);
        that.$refs.popoverInput[index].focus();
      }, 50);
    },
```

Other refs in the file are being registered. I assume this is not because the input element hasn't been added to the DOM when $refs is created. I this assumption correct?

Why did it work before? How do I get it to work again?
I'm happy to provide more details and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't so much in the code, as it was in the environment

`npm install vue@2.6`
`npm install vue-template-compiler@2.6`

Then all the original code worked again.

I did change from using a `setTimeout()` to `Vue.nextTick` as I feel like it's a better solution than waiting an arbitrary amount of time.

```
openPopup(person, index) {
      person.showContainer = !person.showContainer;
      let that = this;
      Vue.nextTick()
      .then(function () {
        const ref = that.getId(index);
        that.$root.$emit("bv::show::popover", ref);
        that.$refs.popoverInput[index].focus();
      })  
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Popovers and Tooltip were complete re-written in the `2.0.0` release, if this is a project which was upgraded from the `rc-*` versions, that's probably why it stopped working.

It looks like you're using the ref to focus the input after opening the popover.

`<b-form-input>` supports a `autofocus` prop which focuses the input when the component is mounted. And since `<b-popover>` is `lazy` it will only be mounted when the popover is shown.

```html
<b-popover :target="getId(index)" triggers="focus" placement="top">
  <b-form-input v-model="person.comment" autofocus placeholder="Skriv beskrivning">
</b-popover>
```

Comment: Previously when I tried to open the popover I got the error:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

When I make the suggested changes, I get nothing at all. The popover still doesn't open

Comment: Since you're using `getId(index)`, to set both the `id` and `target`. Shouldn't you also use that here `that.$root.$emit("bv::show::popover", "popover-" + index);`, to define which popover should show? Additionally, is the popover target visible when you try to show the popover?

Comment: I have that in the `setTimeout()` function of `openPopup()`
I have tried removing the setTimeout and I have tried setting regular ids just to test and I still can't get them to show again

Comment: You have `const ref = that.getId(index);`, but `ref` isn't used anywhere. That's why i mentioned it. You could also try increasing the timeout to see if its a timing issue. Just noticed you're using a old version of Vue as well. Vue `2.6` is required, while you're on `2.5`

Comment: I upgraded to vue@2.6.12 and now at least I have the popover appearing. Thanks. I hope I can work the rest out from here